# Names of different kinds

Tags: riddle, word, geography, anagram

> My first 2 are a Chinese surname.
>   My last 2 are a Chinese surname.
>
> My first 3 are a boy's name.
>   My middle 2 are a boy's name.
>   My last 3 are a boy's name.
>
> My anagram is a boy's name.
>   My other anagram is a girl's name.
>   My other anagram is a geographical name.
>   My whole is a geographical name.

What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Mali

My first 2 are a Chinese surname.

> Ma [馬](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma_(surname))

My last 2 are a Chinese surname.

> Li [李](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_(surname_%E6%9D%8E))

My first 3 are a boy's name.

> Mal

My middle 2 are a boy's name.

> Al

My last 3 are a boy's name.

> Ali

My anagram is a boy's name.

> Liam

My other anagram is a girl's name.

> Mila

My other anagram is a geographical name.

> [Lima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima)

My whole is a geographical name.

> [Mali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mali)